# OpenCL Out of Resources - Crash at code line which is not reached at that moment

Tags: c++, opencl

i'm doing some OpenCL programming and at one location in my code I get strange error.

a and a_end are pointers to local memory

```
if (a+POS<=a_end) {
    max = ....
} else {
    max = *(a_end-1);
}
```

In my case "else" isn't reached in the current loop. However, the application crashes with -5 CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES if the line is part of the code.
If I comment the line the program works well. This is very strange.

Do you have any suggestions?

Regards,
Chris

**Edit: Some more code**

Values of a, a_end and POS1 before it crashes:
a: 3298304 
a_end: 3311264 
POS1: 34

```
border=b-b_end; //TODO: Check if all dummy elements are removed in this case
if(POS1<border && a+POS1<a_end) {
    s_data[POS1+s_maxes[2]-border+1]=a[POS1];
    s_ids[POS1+s_maxes[2]-border+1] = a_pos+POS1;
}

if(POS1+1==border) {
    debug[0] = a+POS1;
    debug[1] = a_end;
    s_maxes[1]=*(b_end-1);

    if(a+POS1<=a_end) {
        s_maxes[0]=s_data[s_maxes[2]];
    } else {
        s_maxes[0]=*(a_end-1); //Here is the line where it crashes
    }
}
if(POS2<border && a+POS2<a_end) {
    s_data[POS2+s_maxes[2]-border+1]=a[POS2];
    a_pos+POS2;
}
if(POS2+1==border) {
    s_maxes[1]=*(b_end-1);
    if(a+POS2<=a_end) {
        s_maxes[0]=s_data[s_maxes[2]];
    } else {
        s_maxes[0]=*(a_end-1);
    }
}
a+=border;a_pos+=border;
```

Comment: Did you debug it and are you sure that line does not get executed? In any way, there is too little info to go from here. How is max used further on would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the following scenario happens: before your `if` the value of `a_end` is corrupted, highly possibly it gets initialized to 0 (without further knowledge of  the code this is my best shot, but it also might be a value which is smaller than `a + POS`) and then obviously the else branch gets executed which tries to de-reference the value found at address `0 - 1` which is a pretty big number and then the application crashes. Obviously if you remove the else branch this code is not executed.

Hint: Put some printouts for the value of a_end.

Comment: So here are my outputs before the if/else:
a: 3298304
a_end: 3311264
POS: 34

Comment: ok, they look nice ... in this case could you share a little bit more code before/after this if, it's pretty difficult to find an error here? Thx

Comment: ok :) What is the type of: s_maxes and a_end. I assume they are some sort of a pointer to something. Do they point to the same kind of element?

Comment: a_end points to the position after the last element of a. s_maxes stores different maximum values which are used to compare list elements and do actions based on the data

Comment: I did a couple more tests and the program definitely doesn't pass this line of code in my example. So it's really weird that the program crashes if the line is part of the program.